# Your most persuasive arguments in favor of automating a process

Tags: automation, culture

**How do you convince people (i.e. non-programmers) that automating a process is a GOOD thing?**

The common argument against is something like "But you *only* have to do [X mindnumbing task]" and "it *only* takes [Y mindnumbing time], just do it and don't waste time trying to change things."

Any other programmers working in non-dev jobs where automation is useful but is shunned, misunderstood, feared, etc? How did you get around it? Do you argue with logic?

Me? I'm sort of working in secret, but that could bite me in the ASCII.

Comment: Hey @JohnMetta - it's been a few years since you originally asked this.  I hope you managed to convince the people you were trying to convince; and that if not, you found a more fulfilling job to move to.

Comment: @JonTopper HA! I actually moved out of Governmental science work into full time software development… so, I guess you could say it was the latter :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stress the repeatability.  Repeatability and consistency are the often overlooked but highly useful side effects of automation; when you're using automation, things get done in the same way each time, and that repeatability tends to be independent of user fatigue, boredom, etc.

Comment: and when things aren't done in the same way each time, you introduce Hours of Fun trying to figure out why some results are different from others.  The time cost of dealing with mistakes is not to be underestimated!

Comment: @JustJeff: and let's not forget that those Hours of Fun tend to be single digit ones which end with AM...  :-)

Comment: This is one I actually hadn't considered- and I'm in scientific data processing. I'll work angle in the name of data veracity and consistency... without mentioning programming bugs :-)

Answer (score 5):

Logic?  All you need is a cost-benefit analysis.  Break your time down into an hourly rate, multiply by the number of times you have to perform the task in a year and the amount of time it takes, and then compare it to the cost of automating the procedure.

It's usually glaringly obvious after that.  Of course, theoretically all the time you save is put to productive use elsewhere, but how do you prove that?  ;)

Answer (score 2):

Ask them: "When you want 100 photocopies of a document, do you manually feed it through the copier  100 times?"

Actually, thinking about it, some people probably do :-(

Comment: That's actuall good one. Wouldn't work at my last job (Boss thought that copies weren't as "original" if fed... I know, I said "Last job"). Straight cost benefit has been tried before (not at current job) and shunned because "new processes always have large longterm costs."

Answer (score 2):

There's a great quote by Terence Parr, creator of ANTLR:

> Why spend 5 days coding something by hand that you could spend five years automating?

First, make sure you aren't doing that.

Second, just try to make it so you can use the automation without it affecting anyone else. Let people see how much faster you can get your work done... then show them how.